# Spring Boot API and thymeleaf + bootstrap for sending email

Tags: html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am working on a spring boot REST API which just exposes the back end logic. We have the forgot password functionality, which has to send the email to the user. I have used the thymeleaf template engine for that.  The folder structure looks like this on the API side.

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeOMq.png)

We also has the web application developed by different front end people. I have the following questions now.

1. where should i keep this thymeleaf templates? on API side or will it work if I give it to the web developer
2. I have tried to use the css in the thymeleaf. I have kept the css as shown in the attached image which is not working. Should i keep the css on the web application side?

Comment: hi, how are you referring to the CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a function to reset the password by email before, you can look at this code,First define the email format and style in the template file, and then render the value to the template. The image cannot be placed in the email, and the image must be converted to base64 format
[createNewPassword](https://github.com/haiCheng-76/heron/blob/b278d86e72764a5196978ad253c8574d687204fb/src/main/java/website/lhc/heron/controller/LoginController.java#L144)